# Non-static object from a static method

Tags: c#, class, static, return, non-static

I have a simply C# class.

In this class I have an object, that is initialized in the constructor of the class itself.

I make some mods/update to the attribute of this class (I have did it step by step debugging).

From another class, I want to get this objects updated, so I made a static method, which returns this objects.

But whem I call this method, I get the object with value of the initialitation, not with the new values. Why? Is it wrong? How can I get it?

This is a simplier version of my code:

```
public class class1 
{
    private static MyObject p_var;
    public  MyObject MyVar
    {
        get { return p_var; }
        set { p_var= value; }
    }

    public static MyVar getVar(){
        MyVar w = p_var;
        return w;
    }

    public class1() {
        Debug.WriteLine("kjkjkj");

        MyVar= new MyObject ();
        MyVar.attr1 = "test init";

   }
}
```

EXAMPLE: If I call getVar from another class, I get the MyVar object with attr1 value like "test init" and not the new modded valuel.

Comment: error while writing the example code.. now it's correct, thank you!

Comment: You are not initializing p_var, and attr1 is not described in this code example

Comment: @helgeheldre I have forget to write here the init of p_var.. attr1 is only a generic attribute, please focus on the question!

Comment: @PieroAlberto can't focus on the question because the question is WRONG and doesn't make sense...`p_var` is NEVER set...where do you set `p_var`?

Comment: @Leo in the set of MyVar... it works, ok? with the debug, I see the  p_var updated!

Comment: @PieroAlberto thanks for the update mate...I was wondering what `w` was

Comment: If I guess it correctly  the OP is trying to create a new instance of Class1 which call the constructor again and reinitialize the initial value of the private static object

Comment: My question is to the point : if your attr1 is a static element on the class creating a new instance of that class will not update the static value

Comment: @KamelBRAHIM: I think so too. It is in my answer. There is no other way for the value to reset.

Comment: @KamelBRAHIM attr1 is not static

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, you are missing some `static`s here. You should get one on `MyVar` and the `class1` constructor. In this case, the value doesn't get reset when calling `new class1()` for the second time:

```
public class MyObject { public string attr1 { get; set; } }

public class class1
{
    public static MyObject MyVar // <-- here
    {
        get;
        private set; // <-- made private to prevent changes from the outside
    }

    // public static MyObject getVar() // use MyVar instead
    //{
    //    return MyVar;
    //}

    public static class1() // <-- here
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("kjkjkj");

        MyVar = new MyObject();
        MyVar.attr1 = "test init";
    }
}
```

You could simplify this using a simple singleton implementation:

```
public class class1
{
    private static MyObject p_var;
    public static MyObject MyVar
    {
        get
        {
            if (p_var == null)
            {
                p_var = new MyObject();
                p_var.attr1 = "test init";
            }

            return p_var;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @PatrickHofman...yeah, I think he's got a design issue and by the looks of it he'd better off turning this class into a singleton in order to prevent double initialization of the singleton object. However, as it stands, it still doesn't explain why the static object gets resets if he's not explicitly calling the instance constructor or property setter. I believe he must be calling the instance ctor somewhere else

Comment: @Leo: I think your point is in: *if he's not explicitly calling the instance constructor*... he is. He can't get `MyVar` from another class since it isn't `static`. He has to initialize a new `class1`.

Comment: @Leo I call the method with MyNamespace.MyClass.getVar()... it works but also reset the var, so I think it calls automatically the init

Comment: @PatrickHofman singleton implementation... it seems to work, thanks a lot man!!!! :)

Comment: +1 @PatrickHofman absolutely, I guess what I wanted to say was that "it doesn't necessarily mean this ctors is getting called from another class"...it could be an app component lifecycle issue, etc, etc....no details provided...overall, you already pointed out the most important thing...design issues